# Swashbucke Date example showing time component/wrong format

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.examples

We specify an input property with an example value as such

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Start date in format YYYY-MM-DD
/// </summary>
/// <example>2020-05-31</example>
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? From { get; set; }
```

And produces the following json

```json
{
  "name": "from",
  "in": "query",
  "description": "Start date in format YYYY-MM-DD",
  "schema": {
    "type": "string",
    "description": "Start date in format YYYY-MM-DD",
    "format": "date",
    "nullable": true,
    "example": "31/05/2020 12:00:00 AM"
  }
}
```

it looks like the example is not respecting the swagger date format which is: [full-date](https://swagger.io/specification/#data-types) of format [YYYY-MM-DD](https://xml2rfc.tools.ietf.org/public/rfc/html/rfc3339.html#anchor14)

The setup code I used:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(swaggerGenOption =>
    {
        swaggerGenOption.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });
        swaggerGenOption.IncludeXmlComments(XmlDocPath<Startup>());
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(config =>
    {
        config.RoutePrefix = string.Empty
        config.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v1/swagger.json", "TST");
    });
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
}
```

Comment: What version of swashbuckle are you using?

Comment: I just tested on my side and I do get it with the right format: http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Date#/Date/Date_Post

Comment: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.4.1

Comment: Argh, a bit more digging: it seems like this is fixed just after 5.4.1 (may 13th) https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/commit/8ff7b32838e46ca0f748bd3f443840fbb07fd45d

Comment: It appears that 5.5.0 changed the behavior but not fixed it :( ... now the date format seems to be the same as date-time

Comment: report it on the project